# Linking javascript variables to object values.

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I was looking at Backbones v1.0.0 source code and noticed something interesting. In the Backbone.Events object the "**on**" method seems to be *linking* a variable to an object value:

```
 on: function(name, callback, context) {
     if (!eventsApi(this, 'on', name, [callback, context]) || !callback) return this;
     this._events || (this._events = {});
     var events = this._events[name] || (this._events[name] = []);
     events.push({callback: callback, context: context, ctx: context || this});
     return this;
},
```

The "**events**" variable is set to the "**this._events[name]**" value which is either an existing array or set to an empty array. The strange part is the next line that pushes an object into this array. After the push, if you now check the value of "**this._events[name]**", it now has that new object at the end of its array. To me, it looks like the two are essentially *linked*; when you update one the other becomes updated too.

I've haven't run across something like this before and doing a simple browser console test confirms this behavior. You update one, and the other gets the update too. It only seems to work with object values that are arrays though. Can anyone explain what is happening here? Im a bit confused?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After that `var events = this._events[name] || (this._events[name] = []);` line, both the `events` variable and `this._events[name]` point to the **same** array. Since they both point to the same array, it doesn't matter whether you do `events.push(...)` or `this._events[name].push(...)`, it will push an element on the one array both things are pointing to.

This is exactly the same as this:

```
var a = [];            // Create an empty array, reference it from `a`
var b = a;             // Now, `b` and `a` both point to the same array
a.push("foo");         // Put an entry in the array
console.log(a.length); // "1", unsurprisingly
console.log(b.length); // "1", because both `a` and `b` point to the same array
```

Answer (score 1):

> You update one, and the other gets the update too.

You only have one array, and it's getting updated.

Think of variables as "pointers", when they have an object as a value (yes an array counts as an object).  The variable is not the object, it simply holds a reference to that object.

This can be demonstrated more simply by this snippet:

```
var a = [];
var b = a;
a.push('Hello!');
alert(b[0]); // Hello!
```

You only have one array here, and both the `a` and `b` variables point to that same array.  You modify that array, and those modifications can be fetched from any variable that points to that array.

Answer (score 0):

Actually what's happening is a simple way to initialize events to an array if it doesn't already exist.  Events is a pointer that points to `this._events[name]` which itself is a pointer that points to an array.  If the array doesn't exist it's initialized to a new array.

Try this:

```
var x = false || 2;
console.log(x);
x = 1 || 2;
console.log(x);
```